# Serverless error in dynamo get ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, dynamodb-queries

I'm using serverless to create and query a DynamoDB database table, but when not querying using the primary key I get this error:

`INFO Error in dynamo get ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`

I have another key setup as a GSI, but I still get the error.

**serverless.yml**

```
...

resources:
  Resources:
    BeaconTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: venue-table
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: VenueID
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: VenueID
            KeyType: HASH
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

**Dynamo.js**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const Dynamo = {
    async get(TableName){
        const params = {
            TableName,
            Key:{
                "BeaconAddr": <string> // Hardcoded string
            }
        };

        const data = await documentClient
            .get(params)
            .promise()

        if (!data || !data.Item){
            throw Error(`There was an error fetching the data for ID of ${ID} from ${TableName}`)
        }
        console.log(data);

        return data;
    },

    async write(data, TableName){
        if (!data.ID){
            throw Error('no ID on the data');
        }

        const params = {
            TableName,
            Item: data
        };

        const res = await documentClient.put(params).promise();

        if (!res) {
            throw Error(`There was an error inserting ID of ${data.ID} in table ${TableName}`)
        }

        return data;
    }

};

module.exports = Dynamo;
```

The query works when the key is "VenueID", but when I change it to "BeaconAddr" (Which is a GSI) the error appears. What am I doing wrong?

Below is a diagram of the table:

[image: Diagram of Table]

Comment: The table you're showing from your serverless.yml file doesn't include a GSI.

Comment: I read that you aren't able to do that? Can you give an example how?

Comment: Add a `GlobalSecondaryIndexes` property to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `get` operation in DynamoDB is only available on the primary key of the table. Your table definition (as shown in the `serverless.yml`) only includes a partition key (aka HASH), so the only way to use the `get` operation is to request a single item by the key (which you have named `VenueID`). If your intent is to have the sort key (aka RANGE) be the `SK` attribute, and the partition key be the `PK` attribute, then your table definition needs to look something like this:

```yaml
    BeaconTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: venue-table
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: PK
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: SK
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: PK
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: SK
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

Note that there is no mention of `VenueID` or `BeaconAddr` in the definition. You would put the values, as you have in the display above, into those fields. To add a GSI, as you have displayed, you'd need to have this:

```yaml
    BeaconTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: venue-table
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: PK
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: SK
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: GSI-1-PK
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: GSI-1-SK
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: PK
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: SK
            KeyType: RANGE
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: GSI-1
            KeySchema: 
              - AttributeName: "GSI-1-PK"
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: GSI-1-SK
                KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

Note that there are separate columns here. The data that goes into those columns is up to you to populate.

Finally, when querying a GSI (you cannot `get` on a GSI) you must supply the index name in the query.

Comment: How would I query the table if I only knew ```BeaconAddr``` ?

Comment: Assuming you added the GSI, you can query the index by only supplying the partition key. Partition is required on all queries, Sort key is optional and can include operators outside of just =.